# Python list index out of range testing all possible permutations

Tags: python, arrays, list, outofrangeexception

so the following code is meant to test every possible combination of characters untill it finds the one you typed, however at one point it says list index out of range, how do I fix this?

```
password = input()
chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"
guess = ""
chars = list(chars)
chararray = []
for l in password:
    chararray.append(0)
while guess != password:
    guess = ""
    for element in chararray:
        guess = guess + chars[element]
    chararray[len(chararray) - 1] += 1
    i = 0
    while i < len(chararray) - 1:
        if i + 1 > len(chars):
            chars[i + 1] = 0
            chars[i] += 1
        i += 1
    print(guess)
```

the index out of range part is  in the part that says
`guess = guess + chars[element]`

Comment: You're incrementing `chararray[-1]` forever. It will quickly have a value that's greater than `len(chars)`, so that `chars[chararray[-1]] > len(chars)`.

Comment: so how do I fix that?

Comment: I dont rlly understand what you mean

Comment: @ProfMonkey07 The code in your question looks like failed attempt to convert a program written in C to Python. Where did you copy it from?

Comment: its all original python code, im kinda a coding noob

Comment: @ProfMonkey07 It's highly atypical python code. No python tutorial would suggest writing it in that way. But anyway, if you wrote it yourself, you should have no problem understanding the error and debugging it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only incrementing the last element of chararray every loop,  access elements of chars[], which is fixed to 36 elements. For a test input of `hello`, your program will work like this:

```
loop 1:
chararray = [0,0,0,0,0]
loop 2:
chararray = [0,0,0,0,1]
loop 3:
chararray = [0,0,0,0,2]
```

If your program guesses incorrectly 36 times, it will increment the last element of chars 36 times as well, so on the 37th try it will be `chararray = [0, 0, ..., 36]`, and since the inner loop runs for all elements of chararray, it will eventually try to execute `guess = guess + chars[36]`, which will fail because chars only has 36 elements.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it

````
chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"
guess = ""
chars = list(chars)
chararray = []
for l in password:
    chararray.append(0)
while guess != password:
    guess = ""
    for element in chararray:
        print(element)
        guess = guess + chars[element]
    chararray[len(chararray) - 1] += 1
    i = 0
    while i < len(chararray) - 1:
        if chararray[i + 1] >= len(chars) - 1:
            chararray[i + 1] = 0
            chararray[i] += 1
        i += 1
    print(guess)```
````